# Defferent Request content when Send from Collection.create and normal form

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, multer

I tried to use Backbone + ReactJS to build a file upload site, I use [backbone-model-file-upload](https://github.com/homeslicesolutions/backbone-model-file-upload) to help me save file in backbone model and save to mongodb (backend use nodejs + multer)

but I found some problems with this module,
because I used a simple form to upload file without backbone model and used multer to process in backend, and it worked fine.

so I look deeper in the request I send from backbone model save( I use collection.create() ) and the request send from normal form, here is what I got:

normal form:
[image]

backbone model with [backbone-model-file-upload](https://github.com/homeslicesolutions/backbone-model-file-upload):
[image]

It is apparent that the Request payload is a mess in backbone model, right?
why are there two Content-disposition ? and with the wrong name, the name should be the input's name, like

Can anyone know what's going on?

I'm not sure if I looking up in the right place, please tell me if I wrong and I appreciated your help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Okay...after couple hours suffering, I figure out what's happened, it's pretty simple actually...

Turns out, the ***Input Name*** in `multer({ storage: storageConfig }).single('Input Name')`  should be same with backbone model's attribute (key)

for example, if my backbone model looks like

```
app.File = Backbone.Model.extend({
    idAttribute : '_id',
    urlRoot: '/db/collections',
    fileAttribute: 'uploadFile',
    defaults: {
        _id: null,
        title: ''
    }   
});
```

then, my multer should looks like

```
`multer({ storage: storageConfig }).single('uploadFile')`
```

and of cause when you try to create and save model in collection,
you have to specify the same attribute value

for example:

```
var file_data = $(".new-file").prop("files")[0];   // Getting the properties of file from file field
        var fileName = $(".new-file").val().split('/').pop().split('\\').pop();
            if (fileName) {
            this.props.files.create({
                title: fileName,
                uploadFile: file_data
            },{ formData: true , wait: true});
            ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.newField).value = '';
        }
```

That's it.

But I'm not sure is it ok to get req.body in this solution.. I'll update later if I figure it out.

Thanks.